# Update to the database - FLEX

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, crud

I am working with a payment tracking mobile app in Flash Builder 4.6. I am using Flex data management system. I have few issues which are addressed as below:

1. When I add a contact and click save button, the new contact will be update instantly in the database. The "Add" "Delete" "Read" work well, only when comes to "Update", it just won't work. I clicked on the save button, there is no response - no error code at all.

**The code** (AddEditView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
        xmlns:studentsservice="services.studentsservice.*"
        title="Add Student" add="view1_addHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            protected function saveBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (currentState=="Add"){
                    var students:Students = new Students();
                    students.firstname = firstnameTextInput.text;
                    students.lastname = lastnameTextInput.text;
                    students.cellphone = cellphoneTextInput.text;
                    students.email = emailTextInput.text;
                    students.address = addressTextInput.text;
                    students.class_id =  parseInt(classidTextInput.text);
                    students.photofile = photofileTextInput.text;


                    createStudentsResult.token = studentsService.createStudents(students);
                    studentsService.commit();
                } else {
                    /* updateStudentsResult.token = studentsService.updateStudents(students);
                    studentsService.getDataManager(studentsService.DATA_MANAGER_STUDENTS).autoCommit=false;  */
                /*  students.firstname = firstnameTextInput.text;
                    students.lastname = lastnameTextInput.text;
                    students.cellphone = cellphoneTextInput.text;
                    students.email = emailTextInput.text;
                    students.address = addressTextInput.text;
                    students.class_id =  parseInt(classidTextInput.text);
                    students.photofile = photofileTextInput.text; */
                     updateStudentsResult.token = studentsService.updateStudents(students);
                    /* studentsService.getDataManager(studentsService.DATA_MANAGER_STUDENTS).autoCommit=false */;
                } 
            }

            protected function createStudentsResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                navigator.replaceView(StudentDetail,event.result as int);
            }

            protected function cancelBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigator.popView();
                studentsService.commit();
            }

            protected function view1_addHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if(data == null){
                    currentState ="Add";
                } else {
                    currentState ="Edit";
                    students = data as Students;
                    title ="Edit Student";
                }
            }

            protected function updateStudentsResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                navigator.popView();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="Add"/>
        <s:State name="Edit"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <valueObjects:Students id="students"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="createStudentsResult" result="createStudentsResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <studentsservice:StudentsService id="studentsService"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="updateStudentsResult" result="updateStudentsResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button id="cancelBtn" label="Cancel" click="cancelBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="saveBtn" label="Save" click="saveBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">
            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="First Name"/>
            <s:TextInput id="firstnameTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.firstname}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Last Name"/>
            <s:TextInput id="lastnameTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.lastname}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Cellphone"/>
            <s:TextInput id="cellphoneTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.cellphone}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Email"/>
            <s:TextInput id="emailTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.email}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Address"/>
            <s:TextInput id="addressTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.address}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Class ID"/>
            <s:TextInput id="classidTextInput" width="100%" text="{students.class_id}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Photo file"/>
            <s:TextInput id="photofileTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.photofile}"/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:View>
```

**The code** (StudentView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
        xmlns:studentsservice="services.studentsservice.*"
        title="Add Student" add="view1_addHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            protected function saveBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (currentState=="Add"){
                    var students:Students = new Students();
                    students.firstname = firstnameTextInput.text;
                    students.lastname = lastnameTextInput.text;
                    students.cellphone = cellphoneTextInput.text;
                    students.email = emailTextInput.text;
                    students.address = addressTextInput.text;
                    students.class_id =  parseInt(classidTextInput.text);
                    students.photofile = photofileTextInput.text;


                    createStudentsResult.token = studentsService.createStudents(students);
                    studentsService.commit();
                } else {
                     updateStudentsResult.token = studentsService.updateStudents(students);

                } 
            }

            protected function createStudentsResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                navigator.replaceView(StudentDetail,event.result as int);
            }

            protected function cancelBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigator.popView();
                studentsService.commit();
            }

            protected function view1_addHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if(data == null){
                    currentState ="Add";
                } else {
                    currentState ="Edit";
                    students = data as Students;
                    title ="Edit Student";
                }
            }

            protected function updateStudentsResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                navigator.popView();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="Add"/>
        <s:State name="Edit"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <valueObjects:Students id="students"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="createStudentsResult" result="createStudentsResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <studentsservice:StudentsService id="studentsService"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="updateStudentsResult" result="updateStudentsResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button id="cancelBtn" label="Cancel" click="cancelBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="saveBtn" label="Save" click="saveBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">
            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="First Name"/>
            <s:TextInput id="firstnameTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.firstname}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Last Name"/>
            <s:TextInput id="lastnameTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.lastname}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Cellphone"/>
            <s:TextInput id="cellphoneTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.cellphone}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Email"/>
            <s:TextInput id="emailTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.email}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Address"/>
            <s:TextInput id="addressTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.address}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Class ID"/>
            <s:TextInput id="classidTextInput" width="100%" text="{students.class_id}"/>

            <s:Label paddingTop="15" text="Photo file"/>
            <s:TextInput id="photofileTextInput" width="100%" text="@{students.photofile}"/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:View>
```

If someone has ever solved similar problem like this, please guide me thru this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you put the debug points and check?

Answer (score 0):

My suspision studentsService.commit(); is saving the data into the DB, if the currentState='edit' this code is unreachable. so, in the else block also you have to do a studentsService.commit();

Answer (score 0):

Do you try adding listeners on your service object [(RemoteObject)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractService.html#event%3ainvoke) for "invoke", "result", or "fault" to find out what  was happening?
I think the request didn't send as you wish. Check out the [FaultEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/FaultEvent.html) for more details.